# Firebase for Unity – Offline Persistence

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline-caching

I'm using the brand new Firebase SDK for Unity for an Augmented Reality application that I'd like to function offline. I've used the following statement for offline persistence on iOS before but don't see anything in the docs for Unity.

```
FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

// Keeps a specific location synced.
scenesRef.keepSynced(true)
```

So for Unity, is there anything I can do to make Firebase keep all of its state even after an app restart? Keep a reference synced?

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not supported. I think that the plugin is open source so you can add it yourself. In the end, a unity app is compiled to each platform natively so you can just add the relevant lines in the modified plugin.